# Firestore copy whole map in field to another document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection `ALL_quote` with a hash I generate already inside there is a map called `tmp_ff` with the necessary I want to copy to another collection.

[image: this is the firebase console]

As you see from the picture, I have `tmp_ff` as a map already inside `ALL-quote`, I want to copy all elements inside `tmp_ff` to `ALL_invoice`. Here is what I have so far:

```
const copyQuoteProduct = firebase.firestore().collection('ALL_quote').where("quote_hashid", "==", "9hgr9Myhc70CUalKnT1u"); 
await copyQuoteProduct.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.map(function(doc) {

       console.log("===", doc.tmp_ff); //undefined
       this.copy_tmp_ff.push(doc.tmp_ff.q_p1_category); //undefined also, just test
   })
});
```

I believe snapshot is correct, how come I get nothing from `doc.tmp_ff`? If I want to copy exact element to `ALL_invoice`, and I suppose to have empty map called `copy_tmp_ff` how can I declare everything from `doc.tmp_ff` to `copy_tmp_ff`?

And I will push all `copy_tmp_ff` like this to `ALL_quote`:

```
const ref = collection(db, "ALL_invoice");
addDoc(ref, copy_tmp_ff) //empty right now
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new document to `ALL_invoice` with the data that you marked, that'd be:

```
const copyQuoteProduct = firebase.firestore().collection('ALL_quote').where("quote_hashid", "==", "9hgr9Myhc70CUalKnT1u"); 
const allInvoiceRef = firebase.firestore().collection('ALL_invoice');
await copyQuoteProduct.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.map(function(doc) {
       allInvoiceRef.add({ tmp_ff: doc.data().tmp_ff });
   })
});
```

---

If `quote_hashid` is always the same value as the document ID, you don't need the query or loop, and can simplify the above to:

```
const copyQuoteProduct = firebase.firestore().collection('ALL_quote').doc("9hgr9Myhc70CUalKnT1u"); 
const allInvoiceRef = firebase.firestore().collection('ALL_invoice');
await copyQuoteProduct.get().then(function(doc) {
   allInvoiceRef.add(allInvoiceRef, { tmp_ff: doc.data().tmp_ff });
});
```